# The derivation of Reynolds-averaged Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integration, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, time-series

The following procedure is used to derive the Reynolds-averaged Navier-Stokes equations ([Wikipedia: RANS equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds-averaged_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#cite_note-4%3E))

When we talk about turbulent flows we can represent the velocity of the fluid as:
$$
\tag{1}
u (\textbf{x},t) = \bar{u}(\textbf{x}) + u'(\textbf{x},t),
$$
where **x** = (*x, y, z*) is the position vector. $\bar{u}$ is the main factor and $u'$ is the fluctuating factor.

The continuity and Navier-Stokes equations are:
$$
\tag{2}
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} = 0
$$
$$
\tag{3}
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t} - u_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} = f_i - \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \nu \frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2},
$$
where $f_i$ represent the external forces.

Now, the Wikipedia page says we can replace *u* from (1) into eqs. (2) and (3), and take the time-average of the equations to further get to RANS equation. During the procedure it is said that the following equation is true:
$$
\overline{u_iu_j} = \overline{(\bar{u_i}+u_i')(\bar{u_j} + u_j')} = \overline{\bar{u_i}\bar{u_j}+\bar{u_i}u_j'+u_i'\bar{u_j}+u_i'u_j'} = \bar{u_i}\bar{u_j} + \overline{u_i'u_j'}
$$

**Why is this the case?**

Note:
The time average ($\bar{X}$) of a variable (x) is defined as:
$$
\bar{X} = \lim_{T -> \infty}{\frac{1}{T} \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}xdt}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The equation in the OP is not correct, it should read

$$\overline{u_iu_j} = \overline{(\bar{u_i}+u_i')(\bar{u_j} + u_j')} = \overline{\bar{u_i}\bar{u_j}+\bar{u_i}u_j'+u_i'\bar{u_j}+u_i'u_j'} = \bar{u_i}\bar{u_j} + \overline{u_i'u_j'},$$
the last term is a time averaged correlator.
This follows from the fact that
$\overline{\bar{u}_i}=\bar{u}_i$ and $\overline{u'_j}=0$.

Comment: Yeah, fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: do you understand now why this holds?

Comment: Yes I think I do, the time average goes through the sum, and the 2. and 3. component are 0.